# How to make multiple table into one table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Based on the code below, you can see there's so many tables in the html, how can I make it into just one table instead?

Currently when there is so many tables when I try to forward this html in email, it will break up each table, and I don't want that to happen

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> 
    <title>Mizona</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <style type="text/css">
      #logo img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
      }

      td {
        word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; font-family:'Verdana', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight:normal; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; 
      }
      
      #content-subsection-right-img td, #content-subsection-plain td, #content-subsection-left-img td { 
        color: #555555;
      }

      .desktop-only {
        display: block;
      }

      .mobile-only {
        display: none;
      }

      .align-center {
        text-align: center; 
      }

      .align-right {
        text-align: right; 
      }


      .no-spacing {
        padding:0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }
      
      .pad-cell5 td{
        padding: 5px !important;
      }
      
      .mobile-center {
        text-align: left !important;
      }

      #socialicons img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block !important;
        border: none;
      }
      
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      
      #graphic img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block !important;
      }

      .pad-right-5 {
        padding-right: 5px;
      }

      .pad-right-10 {
        padding-right: 10px;
      }

      .pad-top-10 {
        padding-top: 10px;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .pad-right-10 {
          padding-right: 0px;
        }

        .desktop-only {
          display: none !important;
        }

        .mobile-only {
          display: block;
        }

        #logo img {
          width: 100% !important;
        }

        #logo-mobile img {
          width: 80% !important;
        }
        #graphic img {
          width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        *[class].center {
          text-align:center !important;
          margin:0 auto !important;
        }
        *[class].bottom-pad{ padding-bottom:35px !important;}
        table[class="body"] table.columns td {
          width: auto !important;
        }

        .social-icon td img {
          width: 40px !important;
          height: 40px !important;
        }
      }
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body style="width:100% !important; min-width:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; text-align:left; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; background:#eeeeee; color: #555555;"> 
    <table class="body" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;  vertical-align:top; text-align:left; height:100%; width:100%; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; background:#eeeeee; margin:0; padding:0; " bgcolor="#EEEEEE"> 
      <tbody> 
        <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
          <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:center; font-weight:normal; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; "> 
            <center style="width:100%; min-width:600px; "> 
              <table class="container" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:inherit; width:600px; background:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding:0; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
                <tbody> 
                  <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                    <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; margin:0; padding:0;" align="left" valign="top" width="600"> 
                      <table class="row" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:100%; position:relative; display:block; padding:0px; "> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                            <td class="wrapper last center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; position:relative; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
                              <table class="twelve columns center desktop-only" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; width:600px; padding:0; display:table !important; "> 
                                <tbody> 
                                  <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; " align="left"> 
                                    <td class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
                                      <div class="mktEditable" id="logo" style="" mktoname="logo">
                                        <p style="margin:0px;"> <img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-header-digest-general-v2.1.jpg" alt="eO Logo White.png" constrain="true" imagepreview="false" style="max-width: 600px;" /></p>
                                      </div></td> 
                                  </tr> 
                                </tbody> 
                              </table> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table> </td> 
                  </tr> 
                </tbody> 
              </table> 
              <table class="container mktoContainer" id="template-wrapper" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:inherit; width:600px; background:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding:0; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr class="mktoModule" id="title-date" mktoname="title/date"> 
                  <td> 
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%"> 
                      <tbody> 
                        <tr bgcolor="#2EA049"> 
                          <td style="color:#ffffff; padding: 10px 40px" align="left" valign="middle"> 
                            <div class="mktEditable" id="title" style="" mktoname="title-date">
                              <p style="margin: 0px;">Volume 4 | Issue 11 | 2018</p>
                            </div> </td> 
                        </tr> 
                      </tbody> 
                    </table> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="content-general" mktoname="general content"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="intro" style="margin-top: 20px;" mktoname="intro">
                      <h3 style="color: #88c34d; text-align: center;">Trust the Asset. Trust the Transaction.™</h3> 
                      <p>More and more players across industries are realizing the advantages of digital transformation, making it a competitive necessity for companies to harness digital solutions. Our own rapid growth mirrors this trend, with eOriginal recently being named one of the fastest growing companies in the country.</p> 
                      <p>Entering into 2019, eOriginal knows becoming part of the auto finance digital ecosystem is essential to achieving your business goals. To take full advantage of this continued growth, please join our upcoming webinar which is focus on the auto finance industry. Learn more about digital best practices and how originators and lenders can prioritize tech stack building and expansion.</p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-title" mktoname="subsection-title"> 
                  <td valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsection" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
                      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>eOriginal Named to Deloitte's Technology Fast 500™ </b></p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-left-imgf16aafbb-fc4e-4e27-b799-256623b49daa" mktoname="mod-subsection-left-img-1"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="content-subsection-left-imgf16aafbb-fc4e-4e27-b799-256623b49daa" mktoname="content-subsection-left-img">
                      <table class="columns"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr valign="top"> 
                            <td width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="https://www.eoriginal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Random-image-_0005_iStock-511197926-1024x683.jpg" width="100%" /></p> </td> 
                            <td width="260"> <p class="no-spacing">For the second consecutive year, eOriginal was named to Deloitte’s Technology Fast 500™, a ranking of the 500 fastest growing technology, media, telecommunications, life sciences and energy tech companies in North America. eOriginal's growth of 266 percent reaffirms its status as a leader in digital lending transformation and management.</p> <p class="no-spacing"><a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/press-releases/eoriginal-ranked-on-deloittes-2018-technology-fast-500/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Read more</b></a></p> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-titlef7e9c286-1eb5-44f6-9d0b-5b28ac2afd8d" mktoname="subsection-title-1"> 
                  <td valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsectionf7e9c286-1eb5-44f6-9d0b-5b28ac2afd8d" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
                      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>Live Webinar: Building an End-to-End eContracting Experience in Auto Finance</b></p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-right-img21690d4b-48d7-4fae-a245-7fbbe7765aba" mktoname="mod-subsection-right-img-1"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="content-subsection-right-img21690d4b-48d7-4fae-a245-7fbbe7765aba" mktoname="content-subsection-right-img">
                      <table class="columns"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr valign="top"> 
                            <td width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing">Whether you provide direct or indirect lending, meeting the demands of today’s auto finance market means going digital is no longer a matter of ‘if’ but ‘when’. Join defi SOLUTIONS Chief Operating Officer Lana Johnson and eOriginal's Director of FinTech Strategies John Jacobs for insights on end-to-end digital auto financing processes, from origination to asset monetization through warehouse financing or securitization.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p class="no-spacing"><a href="http://info.eoriginal.com/W-DEC-V-18_Live-Event-LP.html?Lead_Source=Website&amp;Specific_Lead_Source=W-DEC-V-18&amp;Digital_Source=Website" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Register Now</b></a></p> </td> 
                            <td width="260"> <p class="no-spacing"><br /><a href="http://info.eoriginal.com/W-OCT-MG-18_Live-Event-LP.html?Lead_Source=Webinar&amp;Specific_Lead_Source=W-OCT-MG-18&amp;Digital_Source=N-SEP-G-18" target="_blank"></a></p> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Cover Defi Solutions.jpg" height="151" width="269" /></p> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-title3ccba291-3d31-4b47-8f3e-4c143fa31497" mktoname="subsection-title-clone"> 
                  <td valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsection3ccba291-3d31-4b47-8f3e-4c143fa31497" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
                      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>Case Study: MotoLease Selects eOriginal to Digitally Transform Powersports Financing</b></p>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-left-img" mktoname="mod-subsection-left-img"> 
                  <td style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
                    <div class="mktEditable" id="content-subsection-left-img" mktoname="content-subsection-left-img">
                      <table class="columns"> 
                        <tbody> 
                          <tr valign="top"> 
                            <td width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/eO_Job-327_CS_MotoLease_COVER_01112018.png" width="178" height="252" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" /></p> </td> 
                            <td width="260"> <p class="no-spacing">Driven by a vision to disrupt the powersports leasing segment, MotoLease turned to eOriginal to adopt best practices in eSignature and digital asset management. This case study highlights how transformative digital lending technology drove the company's dramatic growth to corner 75 percent of the powersports leasing market. <a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/blog/motoleases-commitment-to-innovation-drives-dramatic-growth/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Read more</b></a></p> </td> 
                          </tr> 
                        </tbody> 
                      </table>
                    </div> </td> 
                </tr>
              </table> 
              <table class="container" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; text-align:inherit; width:600px; background:#ffffff; margin:0 auto; padding:0; " bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
                <tbody> 
                  <tr bgcolor="#2EA049"> 
                    <td class="two-column" style="font-size: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      <table width="100%">
                      <tr>
                      <td width="50%" valign="top">
                      <![endif]--> 
                      <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                        <table width="100%"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 20px 40px;"> <a href="http://go.eoriginal.com/JB3eB005bE0cHk00O000000" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff">eOriginal.com</a> </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </div> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td><td width="50%" valign="top">
                        <![endif]--> 
                      <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                        <table width="100%"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td class="inner" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> 
                                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%"> 
                                  <tbody> 
                                    <tr> 
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://twitter.com/eOriginal/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-twitter-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/57606" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="LinkedIn" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-linkedin-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/eOriginal/58932553996/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-facebook-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px;" width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                      <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/eo-insights/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Blog" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-blog-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40" /></a></td> 
                                    </tr> 
                                  </tbody> 
                                </table> </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </div> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      <![endif]--> </td> 
                  </tr> 
                  <tr bgcolor="#353937"> 
                    <td class="two-column" style="font-size: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      <table width="100%">
                      <tr>
                      <td width="50%" valign="top">
                      <![endif]--> 
                      <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                        <table width="100%"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> <img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-footer-logo-v2.2.png" width="200" /><br /><br /> <span>© 2018 eOriginal, Inc. All rights reserved.</span> </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </div> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td><td width="50%" valign="top">
                        <![endif]--> 
                      <div class="rcolumn" style="width: 100%; max-width: 295px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"> 
                        <table width="100%"> 
                          <tbody> 
                            <tr> 
                              <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> The Warehouse at Camden Yards<br /> 351 W. Camden St., Suite 800<br /> Baltimore, MD 21201<br /><br /> SALES <span style="color: #2EA049">1-866-935-1776</span><br />SUPPORT <span style="color: #2EA049">1-866-364-3578</span> </td> 
                            </tr> 
                          </tbody> 
                        </table> 
                      </div> 
                      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      <![endif]--> </td> 
                  </tr> 
                </tbody> 
              </table> 
            </center></td> 
        </tr> 
      </tbody> 
    </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

i only want to know how i make it into just one table instead of so many from the code below?

Comment: Make use of colspan

Answer (score 0):

You can use colspan to reduce the number of tables in the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head> 
    <title>Mizona</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /> 
    <style type="text/css">
      #logo img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: block;
      }

      td {
        word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; font-family:'Verdana', 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight:normal; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; 
      }
      
      #content-subsection-right-img td, #content-subsection-plain td, #content-subsection-left-img td { 
        color: #555555;
      }

      .desktop-only {
        display: block;
      }

      .mobile-only {
        display: none;
      }

      .align-center {
        text-align: center; 
      }

      .align-right {
        text-align: right; 
      }


      .no-spacing {
        padding:0px;
        margin: 0px;
      }
      
      .pad-cell5 td{
        padding: 5px !important;
      }
      
      .mobile-center {
        text-align: left !important;
      }

      #socialicons img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block !important;
        border: none;
      }
      
      img {
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      
      #graphic img {
        outline: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        float: none !important;
        clear: both;
        display: inline-block !important;
      }

      .pad-right-5 {
        padding-right: 5px;
      }

      .pad-right-10 {
        padding-right: 10px;
      }

      .pad-top-10 {
        padding-top: 10px;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .pad-right-10 {
          padding-right: 0px;
        }

        .desktop-only {
          display: none !important;
        }

        .mobile-only {
          display: block;
        }

        #logo img {
          width: 100% !important;
        }

        #logo-mobile img {
          width: 80% !important;
        }
        #graphic img {
          width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        *[class].center {
          text-align:center !important;
          margin:0 auto !important;
        }
        *[class].bottom-pad{ padding-bottom:35px !important;}
        table[class="body"] table.columns td {
          width: auto !important;
        }

        .social-icon td img {
          width: 40px !important;
          height: 40px !important;
        }
      }
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body style="width:100% !important; min-width:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; text-align:left; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; background:#eeeeee; color: #555555;"> 
<table class="body" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;  vertical-align:top; text-align:left; height:100%; width:100%; line-height:19px; font-size:12px; background:#eeeeee; margin:0; padding:0; " bgcolor="#EEEEEE"> 
 <tbody>
<tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="center" style="word-break:break-word; -webkit-hyphens:auto; -moz-hyphens:auto; hyphens:auto; border-collapse:collapse !important; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; color:#555555; line-height:19px; -webkit-transition:font-size 1s ease-in-out !important; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0px; " align="left" valign="top"> 
        <div class="mktEditable" id="logo" style="" mktoname="logo">
          <p style="margin:0px;"> <img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-header-digest-general-v2.1.jpg" alt="eO Logo White.png" constrain="true" imagepreview="false" style="max-width: 600px;"></p>
        </div></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#2EA049"> 
  <td colspan="2" style="color:#ffffff; padding: 10px 40px" align="left" valign="middle"> 
    <div class="mktEditable" id="title" style="" mktoname="title-date">
      <p style="margin: 0px;">Volume 4 | Issue 11 | 2018</p>
    </div> </td> 
</tr>         
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left; padding:0; color: #555555;" align="left" class="mktoModule" id="content-general" mktoname="general content"> 
  <td colspan="2" style="padding: 20px 40px"> 
    <div class="mktEditable" id="intro" style="margin-top: 20px;" mktoname="intro">
      <h3 style="color: #88c34d; text-align: center;">Trust the Asset. Trust the Transaction.™</h3> 
      <p>More and more players across industries are realizing the advantages of digital transformation, making it a competitive necessity for companies to harness digital solutions. Our own rapid growth mirrors this trend, with eOriginal recently being named one of the fastest growing companies in the country.</p> 
      <p>Entering into 2019, eOriginal knows becoming part of the auto finance digital ecosystem is essential to achieving your business goals. To take full advantage of this continued growth, please join our upcoming webinar which is focus on the auto finance industry. Learn more about digital best practices and how originators and lenders can prioritize tech stack building and expansion.</p>
    </div> </td> 
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-title" mktoname="subsection-title"> 
  <td colspan="2" valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsection" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>eOriginal Named to Deloitte's Technology Fast 500™ </b></p>
    </div> </td> 
</tr>
<tr valign="top"> 
  <td  style="padding: 20px 40px" width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="https://www.eoriginal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Random-image-_0005_iStock-511197926-1024x683.jpg" width="100%"></p> </td> 
  <td  style="padding: 20px 40px" width="260"> <p class="no-spacing">For the second consecutive year, eOriginal was named to Deloitte’s Technology Fast 500™, a ranking of the 500 fastest growing technology, media, telecommunications, life sciences and energy tech companies in North America. eOriginal's growth of 266 percent reaffirms its status as a leader in digital lending transformation and management.</p> <p class="no-spacing"><a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/press-releases/eoriginal-ranked-on-deloittes-2018-technology-fast-500/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Read more</b></a></p> </td> 
</tr>        
<tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-titlef7e9c286-1eb5-44f6-9d0b-5b28ac2afd8d" mktoname="subsection-title-1"> 
  <td colspan="2" valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsectionf7e9c286-1eb5-44f6-9d0b-5b28ac2afd8d" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>Live Webinar: Building an End-to-End eContracting Experience in Auto Finance</b></p>
    </div> </td> 
</tr>
<tr valign="top"> 
  <td width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing">Whether you provide direct or indirect lending, meeting the demands of today’s auto finance market means going digital is no longer a matter of ‘if’ but ‘when’. Join defi SOLUTIONS Chief Operating Officer Lana Johnson and eOriginal's Director of FinTech Strategies John Jacobs for insights on end-to-end digital auto financing processes, from origination to asset monetization through warehouse financing or securitization.&nbsp;&nbsp;</p> <p class="no-spacing"><a href="http://info.eoriginal.com/W-DEC-V-18_Live-Event-LP.html?Lead_Source=Website&amp;Specific_Lead_Source=W-DEC-V-18&amp;Digital_Source=Website" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Register Now</b></a></p> </td> 
  <td width="260"> <p class="no-spacing"><br><a href="http://info.eoriginal.com/W-OCT-MG-18_Live-Event-LP.html?Lead_Source=Webinar&amp;Specific_Lead_Source=W-OCT-MG-18&amp;Digital_Source=N-SEP-G-18" target="_blank"></a></p> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/Cover Defi Solutions.jpg" height="151" width="269"></p> </td> 
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#353937" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-indent-separator-v2.1.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 50%;" class="mktoModule" id="mod-subsection-title3ccba291-3d31-4b47-8f3e-4c143fa31497" mktoname="subsection-title-clone"> 
  <td colspan="2" valign="middle" style="padding: 10px 40px;"> 
    <div class="mktEditable" id="title-subsection3ccba291-3d31-4b47-8f3e-4c143fa31497" mktoname="title-subsection" style="display:inline-block;">
      <p style="margin: 0px; display: inline;"><b>Case Study: MotoLease Selects eOriginal to Digitally Transform Powersports Financing</b></p>
    </div> </td> 
</tr>
<tr valign="top"> 
  <td width="260" class="pad-right-10"> <p class="no-spacing"><img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/eO_Job-327_CS_MotoLease_COVER_01112018.png" width="178" height="252" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></p> </td> 
  <td width="260"> <p class="no-spacing">Driven by a vision to disrupt the powersports leasing segment, MotoLease turned to eOriginal to adopt best practices in eSignature and digital asset management. This case study highlights how transformative digital lending technology drove the company's dramatic growth to corner 75 percent of the powersports leasing market. <a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/blog/motoleases-commitment-to-innovation-drives-dramatic-growth/" style="text-decoration: none; color: #2ea049;" target="_blank"><b>Read more</b></a></p> </td> 
</tr> 
  <tr bgcolor="#2EA049"> 
    <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 20px 40px;"> <a href="http://go.eoriginal.com/JB3eB005bE0cHk00O000000" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff">eOriginal.com</a> </td> 
    <td class="inner" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> 
      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%"> 
        <tbody> 
          <tr> 
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://twitter.com/eOriginal/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-twitter-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40"></a></td> 
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/57606" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="LinkedIn" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-linkedin-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40"></a></td> 
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/eOriginal/58932553996/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-facebook-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px;" width="40" height="40"></a></td> 
            <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50"><a href="https://www.eoriginal.com/eo-insights/" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><img alt="Blog" src="https://eoriginal.wise-portal.com/newsletter/public/social-blog-icon.png" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px; " width="40" height="40"></a></td> 
          </tr> 
        </tbody> 
      </table>
    </td>          

  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#353937"> 
    <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> <img src="http://info.eoriginal.com/rs/907-BBE-942/images/nl-footer-logo-v2.2.png" width="200"><br><br> <span>© 2018 eOriginal, Inc. All rights reserved.</span> </td> 
    <td class="inner mobile-center" style="font-size: 10px; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 10px 40px;"> The Warehouse at Camden Yards<br> 351 W. Camden St., Suite 800<br> Baltimore, MD 21201<br><br> SALES <span style="color: #2EA049">1-866-935-1776</span><br>SUPPORT <span style="color: #2EA049">1-866-364-3578</span> </td>         
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```